# angularjs factory getter setter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, getter-setter

I try to make a getter and setter for the selectedArtikel2 object, but the getter dosen’t work. Have you an idea why this does not work?

```
app.factory('artikelManager', function ($http) {
    var selectedArtikel2;

    return{
        getArtikeln: function () {
            return $http({
                url: 'rest/artikel',
                method: 'GET'
            });
        },
        setSelectedArtikel: function (selectedArtikel) {
            selectedArtikel2 = selectedArtikel;
            console.log("SelectedArtikel wurde gesetzt:" + this.selectedArtikel.title);
        },
        getSelectedArtikel: function () {
            return selectedArtikel2;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What error does you have ?

Comment: What is the requirement. Where are you planning to use these getters and setters?

Comment: Which getter has a problem? `getArtikeln` returns a promise whose value needs to be extracted with the promise's `.then` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is JavaScript error you are call function parameter with `this` as it is member variable of the function

```
console.log("SelectedArtikel wurde gesetzt:" + this.selectedArtikel.title);
```

change to

```
console.log("SelectedArtikel wurde gesetzt:" + selectedArtikel.title);
```

[check my example based ony your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/CFX1f5GNxuKy9nU1nnnH?p=preview)